# Aufgezählte Objekte mit Verb unterbrechen?

Tags: word-order

Meine Frau hat bei einem Deutschkurs am Goethe-Institut den folgenden Satz als falsch angestrichen bekommen:

> Meine Tochter kann schon auf ihre Nase zeigen, auf ihre Ohren und auf ihren Mund.

Angeblich *muss* „zeigen“ hier am Satzende stehen. Für mich als Muttersprachler klingt der Satz aber besser, wie er ist. Ist die Formulierung wirklich zu poetisch, um als grammatikalisch korrekt durchzugehen?

Comment: Der Satz klingt für mich auch normal.

Comment: Was im Sprachunterricht korrigiert wird, muß ja nicht falsch sein.

Comment: @DavidVogt Kannst du das genauer erklären? (Und am besten eine Antwort daraus machen?) ;)

Comment: Der Satz ist perfekt.

Comment: @DavidVogt Das solltest du wirklich in einer Antwort ausführen. Es ist ja eine ernsthafte Frage und für Lernende vermutlich wahnsinnig frustrierend, wenn ein perfekter deutscher Satz als Fehler angestrichen wird, nur weil er nicht in das Regelwerk passt.

Answer (score 6):

Der in der Frage angeführte Satzbau ist stilistisch und syntaktisch vollkommen akzeptabel.<sup>1</sup>

Noch dazu wird er von führenden Stilistikern des Deutschen in bestimmten Fällen geradzu empfohlen. Siehe z.B. Ludwig Reiners in seiner berühmten "Stilfibel" (erschienen 1951, aber nach wie vor ein so solider wie unterhaltsamer Ratgeber).<sup>2</sup> Empfohlen wird es speziell dann, wenn der Satz sehr lang ist und das Verb sonst ewig auf sich warten ließe.

(Ich such nachher noch ein Beispiel aus Reiners' Stilfibel heraus, sobald ich das Buch gefunden habe.)

Aber da's hier um ein Anstreichen durch eine Lehrperson geht: Wenn im Unterricht zuvor die Regel aufgestellt wurde: "Wir stellen jetzt das Verb mal immer schön ans Ende des Satzes, keine Ausnahmen!", dann kann's die Lehrperson natürlich anstreichen. Sie sollte sich bloß nicht dazu versteigen, zu sagen, der Satz sei "falsch". Falsch ist er nicht. Er entspricht nur nicht den von der Lehrperson (hoffentlich klar genug) kommunizierten unterrichtsinternen Anforderungen.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ich verzichte bewusst auf das Wort "korrekt", da ich Sprache nicht normativ betrachte sondern als Summe ihrer Gebrauchspraxis in der Sprecher*innengemeinschaft. Aber wen solche Feinheiten nicht interessieren, der kann hier auch "korrekt" lesen.

<sup>2</sup> Ludwig Reiners: Stilfibel: Der sichere Weg zum guten Deutsch. Verlag C.H. Beck. - Erschienen in vielen Auflagen von 1951 bis heute. Ich verwende meistens die dtv-Taschenbuchausgabe von 1963/1964.

Comment: " ... und das Verb sonst ewig auf sich warten ließe ... " ist m.E. ein so wichtiges Argument, dass man darauf zumindest diesem einen Lernenden gegenüber eingehen muss, auch wenn man die anderen nicht verwirren will. Das als falsch anzustreichen geht in meinen Augen gar nicht. Sehr schön ist auch deine Unterscheidung von *akzeptabel* und *richtig/korrekt*.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist ein ganz typisches Beispiel für den Wandel einer lebenden Sprache und für das Hinterherhinken von Regelwerken.

Als ich noch ein Kind war und zur Schule ging (geboren 1965) wäre kaum jemandem ein Satz wie der aus der Frage über die Lippen gekommen. Aufzählungen durften nicht durch andere Satzteile unterbrochen werden. Schlimmer noch: Attributsätze mussten unmittelbar hinter dem Wort eingefügt werden, dessen Attribut sie sind. (Ich weiß, nach Attributsätzen wurde nicht gefragt, aber sie verdeutlichen das Problem noch viel anschaulicher als Aufzählungen.)

Ein Beispiel:

> Lisa hat die Katze, die ihr letzen Sommer, als es so heiß war, zugelaufen ist, das Meerschweinchen, das ihr die Tante, die immer so stark nach Lavendel roch, geschenkt hat, und den kleinen Hund, den ihr ihre Eltern, die sie, obwohl sie ab und zu ein wenig unartig war, über alles liebten, gekauft hatten, gefüttert.

Das ist ein völlig korrekter deutscher Satz, der allen Regeln für Aufzählungen und Attributsätze genügt, die man auch heute noch in vielen Grammatikbüchern findet. Aber er ist trotzdem völlig unverständlich, weil die Verben so extrem weit von ihren Subjekten und Objekten entfernt sind.

Den Beispielsatz hätte natürlich auch in den 1970er-Jahren bereits jeder Redakteur und Lektor zurückgewiesen, weil er jeden Leser überfordert, aber damals wäre eine Zerschlagung in mehrere Sätze die einzige Lösung gewesen. Etwa so:

> Lisa hat die Katze, das Meerschweinchen und den kleinen Hund gefüttert. Die Katze ist ihr letzen Sommer, als es so heiß war, zugelaufen. Das Meerschweinchen hat ihr die Tante, die immer so stark nach Lavendel roch, geschenkt, und den kleinen Hund hatten ihr ihre Eltern gekauft. Ihre Eltern liebten sie, obwohl sie ab und zu ein wenig unartig war, über alles.

Heute kann man aber auch Aufzählungen unterbrechen, und man kann anstelle der Verben die Attributsätze ans Ende eines Satzes stellen:

> Lisa hat die Katze gefüttert, die ihr letzen Sommer zugelaufen ist, als es so heiß war, **ebenso** das Meerschweinchen, das ihr die Tante geschenkt hat, die immer so stark nach Lavendel roch, und den kleinen Hund, den ihr ihre Eltern gekauft hatten, die sie über alles liebten, obwohl sie ab und zu ein wenig unartig war.

Damit kann die ursprüngliche Intention des Autors, die Herkunft der Tiere ganz beiläufig (also nicht in separaten Hauptsätzen) zu erklären, erfüllt werden, ohne dem Lesen eine unlösbare Gedächtnisübung aufzuzwingen. Allerdings hat sich diese Art des Satzbaues meiner Beobachtung nach erst in den letzten 40 oder 50 Jahren herausgebildet, und als grammatisch korrekt etabliert hat sich dieser Satzbau erst in diesem Jahrhundert.

Wenn man die Aufzählung durch ein Verb trennt, muss man danach lediglich durch ein zusätzliches Wort (hier durch das Adverb *ebenso*) die Fortführung der Aufzählung kenntlich machen. Im Fall aus der Frage würde das so aussehen:

> Meine Tochter kann schon auf ihre Nase zeigen, **ebenso** auf ihre Ohren und auf ihren Mund.

Dieser Marker kann aber zur Not entfallen wenn das erste Glied der Aufzählung nur sehr kurz ist (hier: »ihre Nase«).

Die in Büchern niedergeschriebenen Regelwerke der deutschen Sprache hinken dem tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch aber meist rund 20 bis 30 Jahre hinterher. Die Autoren solcher Regelwerke wollen kurzfristige Modeerscheinungen nicht zu Ehren verhelfen, die ihnen gar nicht gebühren. Was eine kurzfristige Marotte ist, und was der Beginn einer fortdauernden Veränderung, kann man aber erst erkennen, wenn einige Jahre vergangen sind.

Comment: Es sollte zumindest eines dieser ominösen Lehrwerke genannt (besser noch zitiert) werden. Der Text liest sich als reine Spekulation. Alte Beispiele für "Summen von Substantiven gespalten durch das Verbum" bei [Behaghel, Dt. Syntax](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11023511_00274.html), IV, S. 246 f.; z.B. Luther: *Petrus aber antwortet und die Apostel*.

Comment: Einspruch Euer Ehren! Der in der Frage angeführte Satzbau hat gar nicht wirklich was mit Sprachwandel und Hinterherhinken von Regelwerken zu tun. Schon Ludwig Reiners in seiner berühmten "Stilfibel" (erstmals erschienen 1951) **empfiehlt** solches Vorziehen des Verbs (wo angemessen, also zum Beispiel weil der Satz zu lang wird und das Verb darum ewig auf sich warten lässt).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, mir fiel Reinsers auch sofort ein. Und ich hatte nachgeschaut, die Stelle auf die Schnelle aber nicht gefunden. Und auch in Eduard Engels Stilkunst (noch älter) hat das meines Wissens schon gestanden.